# Visual studio designer saves everything to .resx instead of .designer.cs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-designer, .net-cf-3.5

I have just got a project handed to me where the Visual Studio Windows Forms designer saves most of the properties to the .resx-file instead of the .designer.cs file as usual. Its really irritating when .size and .location is placed in the .resx.

Is there a way to revert this so that everything is placed in the .designer.cs file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have you tried setting the form's `Localizable` property in the Properties Window to "False"?**

This corresponds to the form's [`LocalizableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.localizableattribute.aspx), which specifies that strings as well as the location and size of controls are saved to a localized .resx file.